# Please help - our 1998 Honda Civic cranks but won't start

Tags: honda, civic, cranks-wont-run

Our 1998 Honda Civic (D14A4 engine) has only done 65k miles and was running smoothly until... One day while waiting at the stop lights, the engine hesitated, the odometer went up and down and I turned it off. When I tried to start it, it would crank, but not start. It hasn't started since then.

We towed it to our mechanic and he did a couple of tests, changed the distributor and cables but it still wouldn't start. Here are the FACTS:

1. Fuel - the fuel pump is priming, but no fuel is coming out of the injectors
2. Air - no obvious issues. However, several months ago some hairlike stuff started coming out of the exhaust. It turned out it's the back box wadding. This didn't prevent the car passing its MOT with flying colours months later.
3. Combustion - Cylinders 1 & 2 have normal pressure, while the pressure in 3 & 4 is low... Could this be a blown headgasket? It ran really well up till the day it stopped.
4. Timing - we bought the car 10 years ago when it had done 40k miles. We've had it for 10 years and done nearly 25k in it. We have no record of the timing belt ever being changed...
5. Spark - tested and all ok. The battery is nearly new and fully charged.

Any suggestions what might be the most obvious cause of the problem? The car is not worth spending lots of money on and has only been a second car. But it's a shame to just scrap it... with such low mileage and otherwise in good mechanical condition, etc.

Comment: Great first question, and welcome to the site! How did you validate that no fuel was coming out of the injectors?